# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts.js'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, loader, react-scripts

I am creating react app `npx create-react-app my-react-app`

move to the react folder `cd my-react-app`

when type `npm start` I got an error below

```
> my-react-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'Learn\react\react-beginner\my-react-app\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'F:\Front-end\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
Node.js v18.17.0
```

I already searched for solutions and I tried some suggestions:

I try to change nodejs version from 18.17.0 to 20.5.0 and then delete node_modules and package-lock.json and then `npm install` it again but error still exist

Answer (score 1):

If your project path contains special characters like &, ^, and *, it might cause issues in certain cases.
In my case the problem was that the path to the app folder contained a "&". I changed the "&" to "and" and that fixed it.

before-
D:\website design **&** development\reactproject\firstapp

after-
D:\website design **and** development\reactproject\firstapp

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps >>
Windows Start Search >>
Edit the system environment variable >> Advance >> Environment Variables >> System Variables >> Select "Path" >> Click on Edit Button >> Search Path for "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin" Select it >> click on Edit button >> change the Path to "C:\Program Files\nodejs\" >> Click on Ok button >> Restart The Machine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).